# How to find longest word from given letters.<java>

Tags: java

suppose I have

```
String letters="CATOPHAPY";
```

and I have dictionary to check in the form of arrays.

```
String[] dict=new String[996];
```

how can I construct longest word from letters and check it with vocab in dict that I have before

Thank you

Comment: I can write code to do this for you. I charge $100/hour with a minimum of two hours billed up-front. Do you have Paypal?

Comment: How would you want to break ties? Say if the two longest words in this case were 'CAT' and 'TOP' does it matter which one it returns?

Comment: If all you really have is a dictionary of 996 entries, then by all means go through that dictionary one-by-one and check if all letters are present in your string. Sort the dictionary descending on word size.

Answer (score 5):

1. Prepare an array of dictionary words, but such that the letters of each entry are sorted;
2. sort the dictionary itself by word size, descending;
3. sort the letters in your input string in the same order as in the dictionary;
4. go through the dictionary top-to-bottom and find the first entry whose all letters are present in the input. Due to sorting this can be implemented as O(n).

Ad 1, 3.

```
char[] toSort = original.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(toSort);
String sorted = new String(toSort);
```

Ad 2.

```
Arrays.sort(dict, (String a, String b) -> b.length() - a.length());
```

Ad 4.

```
boolean isMatch(String dictWord, String inputWord) {
  for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < dictWord.length();) {
    if (j >= inputWord.length()) return false;
    char d = dictWord.charAt(i), n = inputWord.charAt(j);
    if (d < n) return false;
    if (d >= n) j++;
    if (d == n) i++;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: I have tried many times, but it didn't work.anyway thank you for answering.